# How to combine multiple cells to create one cell with Excel

Tags: excel, time, milliseconds

I have an Excel file containing in 4 columns:

```
hours   minutes seconds milliseconds
9         7          51       905
9         7          58       233
```

How can I put one row of this data into a single cell? My aim is to create a single cell containing hh_mm_ss.000 in order to make calculations.

No VBA, Excel functions preferred.
Thanks.

**The solution I found**

1) concatenate data

```
=CONCATENATE(H2;":";I2;":";J2;".";K2)
```

2) convert to milliseconds

```
=(H2*3600+60*I2+J2)*1000+K2
```

3) computations

4) result back to seconds (=cell/1000) [format cell as general]

Comment: How about using ``CONCATENATE(a, b)``?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate strings using the `CONCATENATE()` function in Excel:

```
=CONCATENATE(A1, "_", B1, "_", C1, ".", D1)
```

If you use a non-English version of Excel, use semicolons instead:

```
=VERKETTEN(A1; "_"; B1; "_"; C1; "."; D1)
```

As arguments you can either use static strings or reference cells.

Furthermore, you can provide as many arguments as desired, to concatenate them. You are not limited to two arguments.

Comment: Quick note: This may be for non-English versions of Excel. Semicolons should be replaced with commas, and last semicolon after end of formula is not required.

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot, however I'm not able to make calculation with such results :(

Comment: If I try to compute the difference between two values obtained with the concatenate command I get and error (#VALUE!). I have formatted the cell as time.

Comment: @Luke He provided an answer in the format exactly as you described in your question.

Comment: Actually there is written that I need to make calculations @ImaginaryHuman072889

Comment: By the way my Excel is an english version, but thanks for the info @ImaginaryHuman072889

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889: Thanks, I was not aware of the fact, that the English version of Excel uses commas instead. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @user1438038 No problem. Otherwise, I agreed with your answer and I gave you an upvote.

Comment: Nono you misunderstood .. Excel in english DOES ACCEPT semicolons! You were right from the beginning!

Comment: @Luke If you type `CONCATENATE(A1; "_"; B1; "_"; C1; "."; D1)` into English Excel, you will get an error.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 The solution I found is: =CONCATENATE(A1; ":"; B2; ":"; C2; "."; D2)

Answer (score 0):

If calculations such as adding/subtracting times are required, probably easiest solution would be to convert all times to seconds and add them up.

For example,

```
= 3600*A1+60*B1+C1+D1/1000
```

I would say this is required to do manually because Excel's built in time system only has a resolution down to the second (not millisecond).